# Entitymanager (JPA/Hibernate) returns Null values in al columns

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I've tried a few things, but for some strange reason the result from a entityManger.createNamedQuery("NamedQuery",output.class).getSingleResult() returns NULL values in Every entity column. However, if a column has a natural default, like boolean they do come with their default values.

My question is, how does Hibernate/JPA work behind the scenes. They seem to be creating Proxy classes, but what could break in my query causing them to return Nulls for all columns?

Thanks

Ravi

Comment: How  about including actual code of `output` class ?

Comment: Hi Antoniosss, Here it is https://pastebin.com/L7WMHTzN

Comment: And further, this is the Debug view in Eclipse of the Null column object that I get https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlwnWi9oY0HVgT3M4mborpSxw32l

Comment: These are the snippet from the query being run 

returnActivity = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findUniqueDEPActivitybyLogbookNo", Activities.class).setParameter(1, logbookNo)
        .getSingleResult();
  
  
    @NamedQuery(name = "findUniqueDEPActivitybyLogbookNo", query = "SELECT act FROM Activities act INNER JOIN act.activityType td "
    + " WHERE act.logbookNo = ?1 AND act.deleted = FALSE and act.rejected = FALSE  AND td.name = 'DEP' "
    + "AND act.corrected = FALSE AND act.authorityChange = FALSE  AND act.fmcAmendment = FALSE"),

Comment: put code in the QUESTION not as a link to some external site. And post what SQL was invoked by your chosen JPA provider ...